# Space station Freedom - purpose (specialisation) of pressurized modules

Tags: history, space-station

A project of [Space station Freedom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Station_Freedom) had a long evolution and eventually ended as US segment of International Space Station.

For ISS we know specialisation of [pressurized modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Space_Station#Pressurised_modules).

**What were purposes of Freedom station's pressurized modules?**

[image]

I found this NASA video:

But this video is not detailed enough to deduce the purposes of pressurized modules.

---

Interesting moments from the video:

1) Cupola-like observation cabin looks in zenith, not in nadir like on ISS.

2) Interiors of pressurized modules have many similarities with ISS. But there is much more messy in ISS modules, with lots of wires and equipment at walls.

3) [Glovebox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microgravity_Science_Glovebox) at Freedom station

4) There is nothing like [Quest airlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quest_Joint_Airlock). **What EVA airlock was planned for Freedom station?**

Because the desing of Freedom station was changed many times, an answer about at least one configuration would be good enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: I found a much better picture from MSFC dated 1991. (Better than the ones I used earlier) It's basically your picture with labels.

[image]

[Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20120611042229/http://www.astronautix.com/craft/spaeedom.htm)

Comment: unfortunately I can't open the link :( And the picture is unreadable. About the airlock - it's very likely, thanks. Are there any other sources available?

Comment: New picture - yes, that is! Thanks! At least two interesting details: 1) docking modules look different from ISS. I suppose they are for shuttle without Shuttle Docking System add-on, to save payload. 2) propulion modules on truss, not on rear end of a pressurised module

Answer (score 3):

I found a picture with better resolution here:

https://books.google.ru/books?id=UcXUUzZlBTYC

page 207

[image]

It confirms that Organic Marble posted.

Japanese module is identical to actual Kibo module on ISS. Crew Return Vehicle (CRV) looks some odd, I wonder what is the structure on its top... But there were [several alternative concepts of CRV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crew_Return_Vehicle). Logistics module is that pointed to nadir I suppose, as [MPLMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-Purpose_Logistics_Module) at ISS.

Beyond the scope - I was also wondering about propulsion of Freedom station. From [this article](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19950006823.pdf) I can deduce that gaseous hydrogen/gaseous oxygen engine was considered. The components were planned to be obtained by electrolysis of water dumped from Space Shuttle fuel cells.